# Applying Coupon Codes using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
if (discnt > 0) { // only if discount is active
amt = Dollar (amt - (amt * discnt/100.0) + 8);
des = des + ", " + discnt + "% Discount, Promotion Code Applied " + coupval + ", Standard Shipping of 
$8.00 Applied";
}
```

The above code works fine with no issues, however I'm trying to get it if said coupon code isn't applied I would like the default price to be applied with an additional ( + 8 ) applied

Here is what I've tried:

```
if (discnt < 0) { // only if discount is not active
amt2 = Dollar (amt2 + 8);
des2 = des2 + ", Standard Shipping of $8.00 Applied";
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be calculating prices at client side

Comment: A bit tangential, but what is `Dollar()`?

Answer (score 0):

If coupon is boolean, you can check if conditional by this way

```js
if (coupon) { // only if discount is active
amt = Dollar (amt - (amt * discnt/100.0) + 8);
des = des + ", " + discnt + "% Discount, Promotion Code Applied " + coupval + ", Standard Shipping of 
$8.00 Applied";
}
```

```js
if (!coupon) { // only if discount is not active
amt2 = Dollar (amt2 + 8);
des2 = des2 + ", Standard Shipping of $8.00 Applied";
}
```

Comment: I could be missing something here but I tried those variables with no clear result, would it be possible if I sent you the entire script?

Comment: if (discnt <= 0) { // only if discount is not active
    amt2 = Dollar (amt2 + 8);
    des2 = des2 + ", Standard Shipping of $8.00 Applied";
    }                                             ***** adding = seem to correct the problem ********